# Tikz bar plot Issues: The histogram is not scaling properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, histogram, bar

I am having trouble with my tikz plot[image], Even the value is 21508 corresponding to drive, it is evident from the figure that histogram is not scaled properly. I do not know why this is happening.

My code is attached:

```
         \documentclass{article}
         \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
         \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
         \usepackage{textcomp}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
        \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}

        \begin{document}
         \begin{tikzpicture} 

         \begin{axis}[title= \textbf{Before Simplification},
                scaled ticks=false, 
                tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
                xbar ,
                width=0.99\textwidth,
                height=0.99\textwidth,
                enlarge y limits=0.15,
                enlarge x limits={upper, value=0.15},
                y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
               axis x line       = none,
               tickwidth         = 0pt,
               xtick=\empty,
               ytick=data,
               y=-1cm,
               bar width=0.3cm,
               nodes near coords={
                            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
                            \pgfmathparse{abs(\pgfplotspointmeta)}
                            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
                         },
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        symbolic y coords = {drive,drive-service,walk,bike,all,all-private},
        legend pos = outer north east,] 
        \addplot [draw=blue,pattern=horizontal lines light blue] 
         coordinates {(21508,drive) (31963,drive-service) (47924,walk) (43923,bike) (53370,all) (56120,all-private)};
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It can be easily seen that in each bar, a length of 21508 is cut - and that is the problem. Anyway, please expand your code snippet to a compilable minimal working example so that others can compile it and make some changes thus it is easier to help you.

Comment: The scaling is probably right, it's just that the diagram starts at 21508.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** as observed by @moewe, insert `xmin=0` to have all bars proportional.

[image]

Comment: I guess the OP actually wants the bars to start at 0 so that the lengths of the bars are proportional to the values. That still does not seem to be the case with this solution.

Comment: The cheap solution is to add `xmin=0,` but real Ti*k*Z/`pgfplots` experts may have better ideas than that.

Comment: @moewe, I edited, if you don't mind. If you wish, post an answer and I'll be glad to delete mine.

Comment: Fine by me. ...

Comment: Adding the xmin=0 helped to solve the problem. 
But I am open to other solutions too 

Thanks